# A jQuery dragscroller with children that have onclick events---can't make them stop firing while dragging

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I've been a lurker a long time here and now comes along a problem I really haven't be able to tackle.

Here's a simple `#viewport` and `.canvas`, the `.canvas` is super wide and `#viewport` has `overflow:hidden`:

```
<div id="viewport">
    <div class="canvas">
        <a href="#" onclick="alert('event fired, boo.')">do not fire on mouse up</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the code I have here, I have created a drag scroller with jQuery, so when you clickdown on `#viewport` and drag it scrolls the contents then snaps it to the nearest multiple of 190 pixels (not relevant but someone out there might want my code)

```
$("html").mouseup(function(e) {
    down = false;
    $("#viewport").animate({scrollLeft:(190 * Math.round($("#viewport").scrollLeft() / 190))}, 150);
});
$("#viewport").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    down = true;
    x = e.pageX;
    left = $(this).stop().scrollLeft();
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (down) {$("#viewport").scrollLeft(left - e.pageX + x);}
});
```

All I want to do is start dragging on the link and when I mouseup, I simply need the link to not fire.

I've tried placing `e.preventDefault()` all over the place but I can't seem to prevent the link from firing when I let up on the mouse.

Comment: Avoid all the trouble and use http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to do `e.preventDefault()` on the link's click event, because that's the one whose default you want to prevent.

Second, doing the above will not prevent `alert('event fired, boo.')` because a click handler attached in javascript will fire *after* the one attached in HTML and `e.preventDefault()` will be too late. You can safely remove `onclick="alert('event fired, boo.')"` from the HTML.

### Edit

A smart solution would be for the link not to be dual-purpose - ie. split the function of dragging from the function of hyperlinking. However if this is not possible, then here's a suggested strategy:

- Suppress hyperlink action with handler that does nothing more than `e.preventDefault()`.
- Get dragability by 190px working reliably.
- On mousedown, read and store link position.
- On mouseup, if(position has changed) do nothing; else simulate hyperlink action.

Comment: When I add `e.preventDefault()` to the link's click event, it will remove the ability to click on the link _all_ the time. I need the click event to be suppressed _only_ if the user started scrolling by dragging the link and letting go of the mouse (at which point the event fires because the link followed the mouse while the user was dragging the #viewport)